# How do you integrate formspree to this message page?

Tags: javascript, html, css, email

**Problem:**

I am trying to add Formspree to my HTML site, but I'm not getting an email.

**Html:**

```html
<form class="work-request" action="https://formspree.io/f/__url___
" method="POST">
                <div class="work-request--options">
                  <span class="options-a">
                    <input id="opt-1" type="checkbox" value="app design">
                    <label for="opt-1">
                      <svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
                      viewBox="0 0 150 111" style="enable-background:new 0 0 150 111;" xml:space="preserve">
                      <g transform="translate(0.000000,111.000000) scale(0.100000,-0.100000)">
                        <path d="M950,705L555,310L360,505C253,612,160,700,155,700c-6,0-44-34-85-75l-75-75l278-278L550-5l475,475c261,261,475,480,475,485c0,13-132,145-145,145C1349,1100,1167,922,950,705z"/>
                      </g>
                      </svg>
                      Small Personal Site
                    </label>
                    <input id="opt-2" type="checkbox" value="graphic design">
                    <label for="opt-2">
                      <svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
                      viewBox="0 0 150 111" style="enable-background:new 0 0 150 111;" xml:space="preserve">
                      <g transform="translate(0.000000,111.000000) scale(0.100000,-0.100000)">
                        <path d="M950,705L555,310L360,505C253,612,160,700,155,700c-6,0-44-34-85-75l-75-75l278-278L550-5l475,475c261,261,475,480,475,485c0,13-132,145-145,145C1349,1100,1167,922,950,705z"/>
                      </g>
                      </svg>
                      Blog/Portfolio Site
                    </label>
                    <input id="opt-3" type="checkbox" value="motion design">
                    <label for="opt-3">
                      <svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
                      viewBox="0 0 150 111" style="enable-background:new 0 0 150 111;" xml:space="preserve">
                      <g transform="translate(0.000000,111.000000) scale(0.100000,-0.100000)">
                        <path d="M950,705L555,310L360,505C253,612,160,700,155,700c-6,0-44-34-85-75l-75-75l278-278L550-5l475,475c261,261,475,480,475,485c0,13-132,145-145,145C1349,1100,1167,922,950,705z"/>
                      </g>
                      </svg>
                      E-Commerce Site
                    </label>
                  </span>
                </div>
                <div class="work-request--information">
                  <div class="information-name">
                    <input id="name" type="text" spellcheck="false">
                    <label for="name">Name</label>
                  </div>
                  <div class="information-email">
                    <input id="email" type="email" spellcheck="false">
                    <label for="email">Email</label>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <input type="submit" value="Send Request">
              </form>
```

**Steps I have taken:**

1. I created a Formspree form and copied the form endpoint URL.
2. I created an HTML form and pasted the form endpoint URL into the action attribute.
3. I tested the form by submitting it, Im not getting an email.

**Expected behavior:**

The form data should be sent to my Formspree account.

**Actual behavior:**

I am not getting an email

Comment: According to their documentation, it should not need more than this - https://formspree.io/html/ Maybe you did not name your form fields correctly? _"I tested the form by submitting it, Im not getting an email."_ - but you must get _some_ response, I suppose? What does it show, after you submit this?